# character "v" alone from CMR font

Tags: fonts

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[timesmathacc]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{splalphabets}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}%
\SetSymbolFont{splalphabets}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}%
\SetSymbolFont{splalphabets}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{b}{it}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{splalphabets}{"76}%

\begin{document}

\textit{v} $v\quad \boldsymbol{v}$
\end{document}
```

For italic, this code is working fine, but I need the bold-italic `v` also from CMR family, how can I achieve this?

Note that these changes should apply only for `math` case only, not in text....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should’ve gotten an error message in the console saying that the font T1/cmr/b/it does not exist, so it was substituting medium-weight instead.

You need the `bx` series, rather than `b`.  I also needed to replace `txfonts` with `newtxtext` for your MWE to compile in TeX Live 2020.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[timesmathacc]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{splalphabets}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}%
\SetSymbolFont{splalphabets}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}%
\SetSymbolFont{splalphabets}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{bx}{it}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{splalphabets}{"76}%

\begin{document}

\textit{v} $v\quad \boldsymbol{v}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

You might consider using the OML-encoded font, which was designed for math mode and contains Greek math letters, as your math alphabet, rather than T1.

An alternative is to `\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[timesmathacc, varvw]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\textit{v} $v\, \nu\, \boldsymbol{v}\, \boldsymbol{\nu}$
\end{document}
```

[image: newtxmath sample]

In `unicode-math`, you would do something like:

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[
   range={\mitv, \mbfitv},
   Scale=MatchLowercase ]
```

You would then use `\symbfit` rather than `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: Awesome, it is working exactly with my requirement....Thanks a lot....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Also, have you tried `\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}`, instead of redefining `v` manually?

Comment: Yes, just now I read the documentation of the same and found what you mentioned....Thanks a lot...